# ActiveMQ Artemis and MassTransit. VirtualTopics queue destinations are auto-deleted

Tags: c#, masstransit, activemq-artemis

Some external system is sending messages to virtual topic: "VirtualTopic.Example".
By using MassTransit framework I'm able to consume from this topic (or rather queue that is bind to address) using:

```
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("ExampleConsumer", e =>
                {
                    e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                    e.Bind("VirtualTopic.Example");
                });
```

However after I stop my application the destination queue is deleted. As a result if external system sends messages when my application is down they are lost.

I noticed that after I change broker.xml and add `<auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>` the queue is not deleted after consumer disconnect, but changing configuration file is not my desired solution.

According to documentation at [apache.org](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#configuring-addresses-and-queues-via-address-settings)

> the above auto-delete address settings can also be configured individually at the queue level when a client auto creates the queue ... For Core JMS you can set it using the destination queue attributes my.destination?auto-delete=true&auto-delete-delay=120000&auto-delete-message-count=-1

but after adding `e.AutoDelete = false;` MassTransit is not appending `auto-delete=false` to url of the endpoint.

Could you point me into the right direction of making queues not being deleted everytime application is closed?

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, the point with documentation does't make sense in my use case as I'm using OpenWire NMS client wrapped around MassTransit framework.

Comment: What client library are you using? The documentation you cited is specifically for applications using the "Core JMS" client. If you're using .NET then I doubt you are using this client. My guess is that you're using the OpenWire NMS client. Please clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right I edited my question

Comment: Have you configured `virtualTopicConsumerWildcards` as described in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/openwire.html#virtual-topic-consumer-destination-translation)?